# C# reading bytes over SerialPort to slow

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using the standard .Net Serialport clas for reading bytes (without events).

My code looks like this:

```
              receivedDataList = new List<byte>();

              _serialPort.ReadTimeout = timeout;

              // First byte has length.
              int bytesExpected = _serialPort.ReadByte();
              receivedDataList.Add((byte)bytesExpected);
              // initialize buffer with expected length.
              byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesExpected];
              int offset = 0;
              int bytesReaded;
              // Read as long as the expected bytes are not reached.
              while (bytesExpected > 0 && (bytesReaded = _serialPort.Read(buffer, offset, bytesExpected)) > 0)
              {
                 offset += bytesReaded;
                 bytesExpected -= bytesReaded;
              }
              receivedDataList.AddRange(buffer);
```

I am reading with 9600 8n1. The reading procedure for 10 bytes takes 34ms. If I read in linux, the reading procedure takes max. 20ms.

Is there a way to read faster, and I don't want to read over events...

Comment: Which part of your code takes 34ms? Furthermore, are you really experiencing a negative impact on your application caused solely by reading the serial port? Is this a real serial port or USB?

Comment: sorry for not beeing clear enough, the whole code snip takes 34ms and it is a real com port. I mean, so reading a lot af bytes will increase the time...I testet it with 20 bytes and it takes 105 ms with c#

Comment: Can you try it with a larger sample size than 10 bytes. I suspect optimizations may be introduced at different levels across different platforms, and with such a small sample, the optimizations might not be giving you a good comparison. Maybe if you read 10,000 bytes total you will see some higher level optimization take effect.

Comment: Try to find out, which part of the code takes the time. Also, create `receivedDataList` with an initial capacity. Of which value is `timeout`?

Comment: Reading 10 bytes at 9600 baud should never take longer than about 12 msec.  Whether it is on Windows or Linux.  A very long time for a modern processor, requiring more is never a code problem.  Surely you are looking at the wrong end of the cable for this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is the implementation of .Net's SerialPort, is there any other faster class to use?

Comment: On my system I have loopback plug that allows me to see what I send, so I cam emulate your 10 byte test.  When I ran your code it took 13 ms. to receive the bytes.  BTW - I use VB.